# nginx proxy forward and stream_socket_get_name

Tags: php, nginx, websocket

How to make `stream_socket_get_name` return the real IP address from the remote client?

```
$ip = stream_socket_get_name($socket, true);
```

The above returns something like `127.0.0.1:39872`

## nginx

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    server_name  websocket.example.com;
    
    ssl_certificate  /var/ini/ssl/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/ini/ssl/private.key;
    
    location / {
        proxy_redirect  off;
        
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout  300;
        
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `stream_socket_get_name()` operates on a file handle. In this case the file handle always connects to your proxy, so you can only get the proxy information. But you see those `proxy_set_header` directives? Those are how the remote IP is and remote port could be passed in. In your PHP, you'd have to check the values for the headers.

Comment: My question is exactly how to get those headers ;)

Comment: Well, I've never programmed for a websocket, but I'm guessing it follows the PHP convention of putting in a variable. Your question is about how to get a system call to get you that, which won't work.

Comment: the native function was just to show what I wanted to achieve